# Reflection in java, methods inheritance

Tags: java, oop, reflection

is there a way to get only the methods that myObject decleard (not only public)
without getting the inherited methods ?

Comment: [`getDeclaredMethods()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods()).

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [`Class#getDeclaredMethods`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethods--):

> Returns an array containing Method objects reflecting all the declared methods of the class or interface represented by this Class object, including public, protected, default (package) access, and private methods, **but excluding inherited methods**.

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume you hav 2 classes name is MyClass and MyParentClass

```
class MyParentClass {
   private void method1(){}
   public void method2(){}
}
class MyClass extends MyParentClass {
   private void method3(){}
   public void method4(){}
}
```

You can use getDeclaredMethods() as follows which is give only the methods of MyClass

```
public class TestClass {
   public static void main(String args[]){
     Method[] m = MyClass.class.getDeclaredMethods();
     for(int i = 0; i < m.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("method = " + m[i].toString());
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a very poor quality answer. It doesn't even link to the documentation, let alone summarise the method description. Whilst it does answer the question, it doesn't do so fully.